# Vertical centering of cells in table with hand-wrapped multiline cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Despite dozens of answers about vertical centering in table cells, I was not able (my fault) to find a solution to an apparently simple need, vertical centering of cells in the same row of hand-wrapped multiline cells.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}

\newcommand{\methoda}[1]{{\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering#1}}}
\newcommand{\methodb}[3]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}#1\\#2\\#3\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\methodc}[1]{\begin{minipage}[m]{\linewidth}\centering#1\end{minipage}}
\newcommand{\methodd}[1]{{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}}
\newcommand{\methoddfix}[1]{{\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\begin{center}#1\end{center}}}

\centering\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.28\linewidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.33\linewidth}}
\tabularnewline\hline
\centering Column 1 & Column 2\tabularnewline\hline
2 lines vertically centered & This cell contains more than one line of automatically wrapped text. \tabularnewline\hline
Fail of vertical centering & \methoda{Hand-wrapped\\ multiline\\ method A} \tabularnewline\hline
Vert. center. fail & \methodb{Hand-wrapped}{multiline}{method B} \tabularnewline\hline
Fail of vertical centering & \methodc{Hand-wrapped multiline\\ method C\\ too much padding} \tabularnewline\hline
Vert. center. OK & \methodd{Hand-wrapped multiline\\ method D\\ too much padding} \tabularnewline\hline
Success column 1, fail column 2 & \methoddfix{Hand-wrapped multiline\\ method Dfix\\ cannot remove\\ bottom padding} \tabularnewline\hline
Just a last row & Just a last row \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My real world table is a `longtable` making use of `multirow` and maybe `tabularx` or some other additional advanced package, and is compiled with XeLaTeX.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `makecell` or nested `tabular`s and a `p` type second column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

With a multicolumn around the automatically wrapped columns:
\centering\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.28\linewidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.33\linewidth}}
\hline
some automatically wrapped text & \makecell[cc]{Some \\ manually \\ linebroken \\ text \\ over multiple lines}\\ \hline
some automatically wrapped text & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Some \\ manually \\ linebroken \\ text \\ over multiple lines\end{tabular}\\ \hline
some automatically wrapped text & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.33\linewidth}}{some longer but also automatically wrapped text}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}


With a multicolumn around the manually wrapped columns:
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.28\linewidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.33\linewidth}}
\hline
some automatically wrapped text & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.33\linewidth}}{\makecell[cc]{Some \\ manually \\ linebroken \\ text \\ over multiple lines}}\\ \hline
some automatically wrapped text & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.33\linewidth}}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Some \\ manually \\ linebroken \\ text \\ over multiple lines\end{tabular}}\\ \hline
some automatically wrapped text & some longer but also automatically wrapped text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update:** To combine manual and automatic linebreaks, you can change the initial column definition to include `\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}` instead of just `\arraybackslash`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.28\linewidth}>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{0.33\linewidth}}
\hline
some automatically wrapped text & some longer but also automatically wrapped text\\ \hline
some automatically wrapped text & some\newline automatically wrapped text with a\newline few \newline manual linebreaks\\ \hline
manual \newline linebreak & more text here\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works well if in the second column you have only hand-wrapped cells, but if I apply this solution to my MWE, which in the second column has both automatic and manually wrapped cells, the left cell in the first row lose its vertical centering.

Comment: I have added an uptade to also incorporate this situation. Depending on the number of occurences of each situation (manual vs. automatic linebreaks) you can chose on or the other method.

Comment: `\parbox[m]` parbox doesn't have `m` should be `[c]` or just `\parbox` as that is the default. (not directly related to your question though)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Just one minor glitch; since in the real world I have several tables and columns with different widths, is it possible to avoid passing the width parameter to `\multicolumn`? Is `\multicolumn` able in some way to compute by itself the width of the column it is placed in? In this way if I change the width of a column I don't have to change the value of the width in each cell of the column, which would be cumbersome.

Comment: You could store the width of a column in a newlength and use it inside of the `p` and `m` type columns. If you then want to change the widht of a column, simply change the value of the length and the column and all its multirows should adapt automatically.

Comment: In my real world table I came across another issue; in some cells I have text which is long enough to need automatic wrapping but I also have to insert manual linebreaks at specific points. Your first solution does not work. while the last row of your second solution, replacing `\\ ` with `\newline`, works except for what seems a wrong indentation. Can you take a look? (just add `\\newline ` after `some` in your last row right column cell).

Comment: To make this work, replace `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` with `>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}` in your initial column definition.

Comment: I just realized that your second solution with the above replacement in column definition, does NOT need at all any cell rewrite. In fact plain cells written as usual support both automatic, manual and mixed text wrapping. You just have to use `\newline` when you need to break lines manually. I think this major improvement is too much hidden in comments, you may want to add a "follow up" to your answer to better expose it.